# Querying Converted record's Owner related field on Lead conversion

Tags: trigger, lead-conversion

I am trying to query the converted Accounts field on Lead conversion, but always returns null. I tried to query these values in different SOQL and returns the value. since i do not want to write multiple queries, tried below:

```
List<Lead> convertedLeads= [
                SELECT Id, Name, ConvertedAccountId,
                          ConvertedAccount.OwnerId, 
                          ConvertedAccount.Owner.Profile.Name,
                          ConvertedAccount.Owner.Contact.OwnerId,
                          ConvertedAccount.Owner.Contact.Account.OwnerId,
                          ConvertedAccount.Owner.Contact.Owner.Profile.Name 
                    FROM Lead WHERE Id = :convertedLeadIdSet];
```

is it possible to query a above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have queried the same fields in the future method and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is doable, you just need to use the correct relationshipname `ConvertedAccount`

```
select Id, ConvertedAccount.Owner.Name, ... from Lead
```

How did I find the relationshipname? - many ways, but Workbench is a typical route

[image]

Comment: I run the above query in workbench and it works. It returns null when this query executed in after update of Lead trigger.

Comment: @gold - you should edit your OP and post the essential bits of your after update trigger.  What is the value of ConvertedAccountId in the after update trigger before the query executes? If null, then you are executing the query too soon in the sequence (that is, lead is not yet fully converted)

Comment: ConvertedAccountId have the accountId in afterUpdate trigger. also if i query the values in different SOQL i am getting values.

Comment: @gold - try using an future or queueable to do your querying

Comment: definitely it would work in future or queueable.